# CakePHP 4.3.2 Populate Form Dropdown menu based on other dropdown menu in same form

Tags: cakephp

I have the following MySQL InnoDB tables:

```
users
   WS_UserID (primary key)
   WS_Username (varchar)
   WS_Password (varchar)
   WS_UserRank (varchar) (can be either: Supervisor | Laborer | Helper)
   WS_UserActive (boolean) (User banned or not)
   WS_UserCreated (datetime)
   WS_UserModified (datetime)
```

```
tasks
   WS_TaskID (primary key)
   WS_UserID (foreign key -> users.WS_UserID)
   WS_TaskTypeID (foreign key -> taskTypes.WS_TaskTypeID)
   WS_Field (tinyint) (for which field the task is created for. If taskTypes.WS_TaskTypeCategory is "Fieldwork", it's required, if "Transport", it's NULL)
   WS_TaskActive (boolean) (Task is incomplete or not.)
   WS_TaskCompletedBy (integer) (If WS_TaskActive is 0, then UserID of user who edited it as completed, else NULL)
   WS_TaskCreated (datetime)
   WS_TaskModified (datetime)
```

```
taskTypes
   WS_TaskTypeID (primary key)
   WS_TaskTypeCategory (varchar) (Either "Fieldwork" or "Transport" currently)
   WS_TaskTypeName (varchar)
```

Hardcoded records of taskTypes: (So these are constant values effectively, but I want to keep it in a database, and not in the PHP files, because there are far more records, but for this question, this will be plenty enough records.)

| WS_TaskTypeID | WS_TaskTypeCategory | WS_TaskTypeName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fieldwork | Plowing |
| 2 | Fieldwork | Sowing |
| 3 | Transport | Wheat |
| 4 | Transport | Corn |

Example tasks records:

| WS_TaskID | WS_UserID | WS_TaskTypeID | WS_Field | WS_TaskActive | WS_TaskCompletedBy | WS_TaskCreated | WS_TaskModified |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 12 | 1 | NULL | 2021-11-22-15:03:05 | 2021-11-22-15:03:05 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 12 | 1 | NULL | 2021-11-22-15:11:45 | 2021-11-22-15:11:45 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | NULL | 1 | NULL | 2021-11-22-15:11:45 | 2021-11-22-15:11:45 |
| 4 | 2 | 4 | NULL | 0 | 3 | 2021-11-22-15:12:55 | 2021-11-28-14:25:43 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 25 | 0 | 5 | 2021-11-22-15:33:40 | 2021-11-28-16:13:25 |

Relevant file folder structure:

```
src/
    Controller/
                     TasksController.php
    Model/
              Entity/
                     Task.php
                     TaskType.php
                     User.php
              Table/
                     TasksTable.php
                     TaskTypesTable.php
                     UsersTable.php
   templates/
              Tasks/
                     add.php
                     index.php
                     view.php
```

In the end, I want to have /tasks to display a list with WS_TaskID DESC order, I am not sure however in many things, since I am new to the whole CakePHP ORM, so I am going to post my questions individually below.

Users could add as many tasks as they want (1 at the time). 
My TasksTable.php file:

```
<?php
    namespace App\Model\Table;
    use Cake\ORM\Table;

    class TasksTable extends Table {
        public function initialize(array $config): void
        {
            $this -> addBehavior('Timestamp');
            $this -> belongsTo('Users');
            $this -> belongsTo('TaskTypes');
        }
    }
?>
```

Note: TaskTypesTable's init has no content, and in UsersTable only timestamp behavior is added.
In the Entities, all are set $__accessible true, except for primary/foreign key values.

My current TasksController.php file: (Note: User data is not yet implemented, it's a fresh project)

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

class TasksController extends AppController {
    public function index() {
        $this -> loadComponent('Paginator');
        $tasks = $this -> Paginator -> paginate($this -> Tasks -> find());
        $this -> set(compact('tasks'));
    }

    public function view($TaskID) {
        $task = $this->Tasks->find()->where(['WS_TaskID' => $TaskID])->firstOrFail();
        $this->set(compact(('task')));
    }

    public function add() {
        $taskTypeOptions = $this->taskType->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('taskTypeOptions'));

        $fieldNumberOptions = array();
        for($i = 0; $i < 82; $i++) {
            $fieldNumberOptions[$i] = $i+1;
        }
        $this->set(compact('fieldNumberOptions'));

        $task = $this->Tasks->newEmptyEntity();

        if($this->request->is('post')) {
            $task = $this->Tasks->patchEntity($task, $this->request->getData());
            //Temporarily User ID is 1
            $task->WS_UserID = 1;
            if($this->Tasks->save($task)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('Task has been added!'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error('Unable to save task!');
        }
        $this->set('task', $task);
    }
}
?>
```

My current add.php file:

```
<h1>Add Task</h1>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create($task);
    //Temporarily hardcoded UserID
    echo $this->Form->control('WS_UserID', ['type' => 'hidden', 'value' => 1]);
    echo $this->Form->select('WS_TaskTypeID', $taskTypeOptions);
    echo $this->Form->select('WS_Field', $fieldNumberOptions);
    echo $this->Form->button(__('Save Task'));
    echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

1: I am not sure if these are belongsTo associations, because I don't really understand the whole concept of these associations. But 1 user can have as many tasks as they would like, and 1 task can have only 1 taskType. Is the belongsTo correct in this case?

2: In the add.php view Form, I want to have a dropdown menu where first users would select either Fieldwork or Transport. This I would prefer if it came from the unique values of taskTypes.WS_TaskTypesCategory column. Then, depending on this choice, next dropdown menu would have different selection options, for example if they select fieldwork, options would be in this example "Plowing", "Sowing", and if they select Transport, options would be in this example "Wheat", "Corn". Then the 3rd dropdown menu, if Transport is selected, it would disappear, if Fieldwork was selected, then a $fieldNumberOptions[] array (numbers 1 to 82) would be selectable, that was set in the TasksController.

3: Next problem, is in the databases, foreign keys, AKA ID numbers are stored, and I don't want ID numbers to be the values of the dropdown menus, I want the names of these records to be displayed instead. I tried referencing them according to the description of Cookbook 3.x, but that throws an  error message: "Call to a member function find() on null" error. What syntax could I use to access the other table's columns's value with just an ID as foreign key in the Tasks table?

4: How could I save the datetime in the database for the created and modified columns? I have the Timestamp behaviour set for the TasksTable, but how do I specify column header names?

Thank you for your time reading and answering these questions. I would really appreciate some help here :D

Comment: You must put a newline before the table markup.

Comment: I did, while I edit it, it renders properly, but here, it doesn't..... Could you pls fix it for me?

Comment: There you go... the fact that it is required on final rendering but not on preview is likely a bug. edit: Apparently buggy the outer way around, but yeah, a bug. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403575/different-table-formatting-in-editor-and-outside